# Where was the issue acknowledgement and apology?

Tags: support, blog

In his blog post today, Prashanth Chandrasekar said,

> We acknowledge these issues, apologize for our mistakes, and have
> plans for improving in the future.
>
> ["Scripting the Future of Stack Overflow"](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/01/21/scripting-the-future-of-stack-2020-plans-vision/)

Can someone please provide a link to where issue-acknowledgement and apologies-for-mistakes-made have been posted? It appears to have accidentally been left out of the blog post.

Comment: As of now, SE hasn't addressed the apology and took appropriate action to reinstate Monica.

Comment: Do you still believe in fairy tales? :)

Answer (score 56, accepted):

They acknowledge the issues in these four words:

> We acknowledge these issues

then apologize:

> apologize for our mistakes

There's no link because the whole acknowledgement and apology takes up eight words, and is done with now.

/s

Comment: I feel better now.  Time to move on.

Comment: It's all in the past now! Let's not dwell on it and now look forward. /s

Comment: Brief and to the point.

Answer (score 20):

The whole relevant paragraph reads thus:

> A key part of great product development is to stay close to customers, listen, and take a thoughtful, data-driven, and research-oriented approach to building products. In our case, it is critical that we work closely with our community to listen, change, and evolve rapidly. As an example, over the past several months, we had a lot of dialog with our community about how best to enforce and evolve our code of conduct. We learned that we needed much better channels to listen to our moderators and community members. **We have not evolved the existing channels of engagement for power users in our community, like Meta, or articulated how we intended to make improvements going forward. This has caused friction as our user base and business have rapidly grown**. We acknowledge these issues, apologize for our mistakes, and have plans for improving in the future.

I put some emphasis on the issue. Basically the CEO acknowledges part of what users have been complaining about, acknowledges that the company didn't do enough on that, and is now apologizing for that specifically.

Notice that if you read the whole text around it, the CEO mentions this as an example of what he noticed could be improved. So probably he meant to apologize for everything else the community has been complaining about as well.

Comment: Upvoting this answer for providing the actual reference, even though the quote itself may be inadequate.

Comment: it is still a very hollow apology with no actual meaning behind it, just more hot air out of SE's mouth.

Comment: @Sorceri I agree. It's specially sad when they say they have plans to remedy this, but don't mention what the plans are.

Comment: It's also troubling that the problem is framed as a failure to "evolve[] the existing channels of engagement," which isn't a thing anybody has complained about; the company has unilaterally disengaged from the channels it provides and used to use. If I ignore someone's calls for months, I apologize for ignoring them, not for failing to evolve my channels of engagement.